# Python2.6 Decimal to Octal

Tags: python, decimal, octal

How can i convert decimal to Octal in Python2.6, for 1 to 100000? I wanna get this converted result as .txt too. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want us to do your homework?

Comment: No, I'm not a programmer. But i do need this for my classification system.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `oct` function:

```
print oct(9) # prints 011
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
text = '\n'.join(str(oct(i)) for i in xrange(100000))
f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```